# Prove that determinant of triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal ennltries.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Prove that determinant of triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal entries.

I want to use $\operatorname{'sgn'}$.I know that $\operatorname{det}(A)=\sum\limits_{\sigma}A(1,\sigma1)...A(n,\sigma n)$.Any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3577797

Comment: Are you familiar with Laplace expansion to calculate the determinant?

Comment: In @ShubhamJohri's link, make sure to scroll past the accepted answer to [Maurice P's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3577797) to get an answer using this particular formula.